# Вывод информации поверх другого активного приложения.

Tags: ios, qt, qml

Существует ли возможность вывода информации поверх другого активного приложения в IOS? Если более предметно, то есть геоинформационне приложение на iPad, и нужно написать метео-информер, который работал бы поверх приложения, не мешая его работе. На настольных ОС это делается при помощи "TopMost" окна, которое всегда находится поверх активного приложения. И если да, то реализуемо ли это средствами Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашел решение в виде Split Over режима. Приложение работает  в маленьком окне поверх другого. Такой функционал появился только в 11 версии IOS, по-моему. Но это функционал ОС а не приложения. Никаких изменений в коде не требуется.